# Parsing a u8 separated vector of FromStr from a BufRead

Tags: error-handling, rust

I need to read a vector of e.g. integers from a stream, usually from stdin but sometimes also from a file. The input is always less than a megabyte, and is sometimes separated by commas and sometimes by newlines.

I'm calling the code directly from my main function, so I'm more concerned with returning a human readable error rather than something that can be caught and recovered from programmatically, hence I'm using `String` as the error type.

```rust
pub fn parse_vector<T: BufRead, S: FromStr>(buf: T, sep: u8) -> Result<Vec<S>, String> {
    buf.split(sep)
        .enumerate()
        .filter_map(|(i, entry)| {
            let entry_nr = i + 1;

            let entry = match entry.map(String::from_utf8) {
                Err(e) => return Err(format!("Cannot read entry {}, {}.", entry_nr, e)).into(),
                Ok(Err(e)) => return Err(format!("Cannot read entry {}, {}.", entry_nr, e)).into(),
                Ok(Ok(v)) => v,
            };

            let trimmed = entry.trim();
            if trimmed.is_empty() {
                None
            } else {
                Some(
                    trimmed
                        .parse::<S>()
                        .map_err(|_| format!("Cannot parse entry {}: '{}'", entry_nr, entry)),
                )
            }
        })
        .collect()
}
```

The above code works as far as I can tell, but I'm wondering if there's a nicer way to deal with the mess in the `match` expression. The functions `from_utf8` and `split` return different error types, but both implement `Display` so maybe there's some elegant way to eliminate some code duplication there that I don't know about (I'm new to rust, coming from c++).

- What are my options to make this code more readable?
- Is it considered bad practice to return `String` as an error type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm calling the code directly from my main function, so I'm more
> concerned with returning a human readable error rather than something
> that can be caught and recovered from programmatically, hence I'm
> using `String` as the error type.
>
> [...]
>
> - Is it considered bad practice to return `String` as an error type?

Yes, it is generally considered bad practice to return `Result<_, String>` when the error returned is formatted from other errors.  The recommended approach is to define an `enum` and implement `From`, `Display`, and `Error`: (using the [`thiserror`](https://docs.rs/thiserror/1.0.24/thiserror/) crate for simplicity)

```rust
use thiserror::Error;

#[derive(Debug, Error)]
pub enum Error {
    #[error("cannot read entry {entry_no}")]
    Io { entry_no: usize, source: std::io::Error },
    #[error("cannot read entry {entry_no}")]
    Encoding { entry_no: usize, source: std::string::FromUtf8Error },
    // ...
}
```

> The above code works as far as I can tell, but I'm wondering if
> there's a nicer way to deal with the mess in the `match` expression. The
> functions `from_utf8` and `split` return different error types, but
> both implement `Display` so maybe there's some elegant way to
> eliminate some code duplication there that I don't know about (I'm new
> to rust, coming from C++).

Your options include:

- methods on `Option` and `Result`, like [`Result::and_then`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.and_then) and [`Option::ok_or_else`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.ok_or_else);
- the [`?` operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#a-shortcut-for-propagating-errors-the--operator); and
- using `.zip(1..)` instead of `.enumerate()` to get rid of that `+ 1`,

plus potentially other things that didn't immediately come to mind.